# How do I change between two images on button click?

Tags: flutter, dart

How do I create buttons (**start**, **loop**) for **two images** changing?
_start() that load *first image* then change to *second image* and end at *first image*.
_loop() that continues to loop between 2 images.

P/S: Better if we can use time like milliseconds to adjust.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Fallow the code below it will change the images using timer don't forget to edit the images.

```
class ImageLogo extends StatefulWidget {
  const ImageLogo({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ImageLogoState createState() => _ImageLogoState();
}

class _ImageLogoState extends State<ImageLogo> {
  Timer _timer;

  int _pos = 0;
  List<String> photos = [
    images/image1.jpg,
    images/image2.jpg
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    _timer =
        Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (Timer t) {
      setState(() {
        _pos = (_pos + 1) % photos.length;
      });
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _timer.cancel();
    _timer = null;
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Image(
      width: 12 * SizeConfig.widthMultiplier,
      height: 12 * SizeConfig.heightMultiplier,
      image: AssetImage(photos[_pos]),
    );
  }
}
```

on your main widget use

```
ImageLogo(),
```

Comment: Thank you! In my scenario, This will not help when trying to manipulate many objects.